# OAuth2 to connect to a 3rd party API with Meteor, separate from user accounts

Tags: api, meteor, oauth

I'm currently building an integration with [Greenhouse.io's ingestion API](https://developers.greenhouse.io/candidate-ingestion.html) which authenticates via OAuth 2.0.

In my database, I have a collection for both users and companies where multiple users belong to one company. I want to easily allow any user associated with a company to authenticate via OAuth to the Greenhouse API, allowing *any* user across the company to access the API.

My assumption is that I will need to somehow authenticate with OAuth and then store the keys in the customer document as opposed to the user document. How would I go about doing this with Meteor 1.3?

I'm using

- Meteor 1.3
- Blaze / spacebars for the frontend.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's strange to me there isn't an obvious way to do this in Meteor. I found a discussion here with links to various projects to achieve this functionality: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/1133